# NodeJS: How to log all incoming server requests to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, morgan

We've setup a NodeJS server for our API, and are currently logging all incoming requests to a file using morgan. In addition to the file-logging, we would also like to store the requests in mongodb (preferably without having to use mongoose). Any help would be greatly appreciated :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mongoose-morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-morgan) or just integrate `morgan` with `winston` and [winston-mongodb](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-mongodb).

```
const morgan = require('morgan');
const winston = require('winston');
require('winston-mongodb');

app.user(morgan('combined', {stream: new winston.transports.MongoDB({db: /*mongodb-uri*/}).stream()}));
```

You can see transport options [here](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#mongodb-transport)